# How to call sails.hooks from inside a model?

Tags: sails.js

I build my own hooks that is works perfectly, tested in any controllers. But when I call my hooks from inside a model definition (/api/model/Somemodel.js), it will throw an error.

If I `console.log` what's inside `sails.hooks.myhooks` it return `undefined` it's like not loaded yet. I don't know how to set an `initialize` or something so my hooks will loaded first. It's independent from `sails object`. I read at http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/customhooks.html at `Timing` section, it just show how to handle `after` some hooks loaded, not `before`.

How to fix this? My `hooks` is just an `object` that I need to use inside my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails hook will load automatically, so it will availability within model's life cycle, not outside. Because outside model's life cycle, hooks still unloaded.